# Product of 3 Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}(x-x_{0})^{n-1}$, how do I find $f^3$? Using the Cauchy Product, I can find $f^2$, which is $f^2=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n}c_{j}c_{n-j}(x-x_{0})^{2n-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar, the inner sum then goes over all combinations of i,j,k, with the constraint $i+j+k=n$. You can parameterize this with a sum
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^j c_{i} c_{j}c_{n-i-j}$$
You should also be careful about your power term, the power isn't exactly correct. You can remove the extra $(x-x_0)^{-1}$ to make it a proper power series. In that case, if the indices sum to $n$, the powers sum to $n$ as well. So,
$$f^2=\frac{1}{(x-x_0)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^n c_j c_{n-j}(x-x_0)^n$$
and
$$f^3=\frac{1}{(x-x_0)^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^j c_i c_j c_{n-i-j}(x-x_0)^n$$

Comment: Notice that the power term in the original series was $(x-x_0)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes, I took it out of the sum to avoid off-by-one powers.

Comment: oh, I see. Yeah, with $n$ starting at $0$ and an exponent of $n-1$, it's not a power series.